# is opening a web page in a new tab considered a popup?

Tags: javascript, popup, popupwindow

When a website visitor clicks on a link, is opening that link contents in a new tab considered a popup? OR a popup must be in a new floating window?

And If this is not considered as popup, What about opening the link contents in a new tab + opening another URL in the original tab?

Example: what happens in coupons websites, when you click " show coupon ", you find a new tab opened showing the coupon, and the original tab redirects to another URL ( may be affiliate URL).

If this considered as popup, so why doesn't google chrome prevent it inspite of setting ( popup : not allowed )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "popup" can mean any of the following depending on who you are talking to and the context:

- A new window/tab
- A new window of a specific size
- A chunk of DOM added to the page which overlays other content

> what happens in coupons websites, when you click " show coupon ", you
>   find a new tab opened showing the coupon, and the original tab
>   redirects to another URL ( may be affiliate URL).
>
> If this considered as popup, so why doesn't google chrome prevent it
>   inspite of setting ( popup : not allowed )

[The rules for blocking new windows are quite complex](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#allowed-to-show-a-popup), but the simplified version is:

**You can open one new window with JS in response to the user *doing something* (usually a click).**